# Convert rows of users to dynamic number of columns

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table like

```
_________________________
|    ACCOUNT      REP    |
|________________________|
|    Tradewind    Bob    |
|------------------------|
|    Tradewind    Joe    |
|------------------------|
|    Tradewind    Rick   |
|------------------------|
|    Headlands    Joe    |
|------------------------|
|    Headlands    Bob    |
|________________________|
```

And I want to turn that into

```
  _________________________________________
  |  ACCOUNT     REP1      REP2     REP3  |
  |_______________________________________| 
  |  Tradewind   Bob       Joe      Rick  |
  |---------------------------------------|
  |  Headlands   Bob       Joe      NULL  |
  |_______________________________________|
```

I have bring trying to figure this out and understand it is some sort of use of the PIVOT keyword. Maybe uses the SELECT OVER somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want three columns, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select account,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then rep end) as Rep1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then rep end) as Rep2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then rep end) as Rep3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by account order by rep) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by account;
```

Comment: Where do you refer to the actual table ? I am confused sorry.

Comment: @punkouter . . . Ooops.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You might use :

```
select account,
       max(case when rep='Bob' then 'Bob' end) as Rep1,
       max(case when rep='Joe' then 'Joe' end) as Rep2,
       max(case when rep='Rick' then 'Rick' end) as Rep3
  from tab
 group by account
 order by account desc;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/OWXO28767)

Comment: Well there are hundreds of REPs and more added daily so I need some dynamic way to do this

Comment: @matthewherb unfortunately, the real dynamic way doesn't exist for such a pivoting operation.